# What do you call this specific way of "running/jumping"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't seem to come up with what this "way of running/jumping" is called.

You start by standing straight, then bending the right leg, then jumping forward by using your right leg, then landing on your right leg first, followed by the left one. Then bending the left leg and then jumping forward by using your left leg, then landing on your left leg first, followed by the right one..

I used to do it a lot when I was a kid while playing, though I never knew what it was called.

Following the accepted answer, I found a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMW4y-UiAvE) showing the exercise(known as power skips) as I remember it.

Comment: What is it called in your native language?

Comment: I can't actually understand what you're trying to describe. How can you use your right leg to jump forward if it's already bent? Surely, you'd have to use your *left* leg, since it would be the only one still touching the ground? And if you land on your right leg, how could it also have been the leg used in the jump?  (Without the actual jumping part, all I can picture is the exaggerated type of motion used by speed skaters, where the leg going forward is moved a great distance ahead and to the side.)

Comment: Skipping, perhaps?

Comment: @JasonBassford yea, I didn't explain that very good :D, anyway with bent I meant like, the foot still touches the floor, but that leg is still more bent than the other one... anyway, doesn't really matter now, the answers did help me find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Skipping** as Lawrence said.  See Part 2 [HERE](https://www.wikihow.com/Skip)

Also, [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWUsF32jdFg) is a video, teaching children to skip.

Comment: The kid at the end of the video does seem to kind of do it, though it's less intensive done than how I remember doing it :D, maybe done slow for teaching purposes. Thanks anyway, I was looking for a video depicting it. Now I just have to find a video showing someone running by doing that, with some speed and jumping height.

Comment: Yes, in a room that small you cannot really do it very well.

Answer (score -1):

It's called hopping or more specifically hopping on one leg because you can hop using both feet at the same time too.